# How many training examples should I take for a convolutional neural network, which takes an input image of 180x180 pixels?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am building a CNN for face recognition (specifically only my face). I would be resizing my images to around 180x180 pixels. How many images should I have in my dataset so as to get good results? For normal neural nets I know the number of features should be less than data set so as to prevent over fitting, but is it true for CNN also?

What I would be doing is just classifying my image as 'mypic' and other peoples image as 'others'.

Comment: I think this question is too broad. First, you need to understand well the concepts of deep learning. There are a lot of sources.

Answer (score 3):

The question of "How much data is enough?" is actually a quite complicated one, and the short answer is, it varies from case to case. For example, if you are using CNN's to determine whether or not a range of colors is present in a photo, you will most likely not need a ton of data for this. On the other hand, if you are using a CNN to try and identify different species of birds in images, you will probably need *lots* of examples.

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127111/how-much-data-do-you-need-for-a-convolutional-neural-network) question sums it up really well, but TL;DR, you should get as much data as you can and measure the error you get by whatever error metric you choose.

If adding more data reduces the error of your test set or your training error is significantly lower than the test error, then it is perhaps a good idea to add more data to further reduce the test set error. However, if your test error stays the same, or worse, goes *up* when adding more examples, this is likely a symptom of overfitting and thus you have too many examples. I hope this explanation makes sense, leave a comment below if you have any questions about this.

**EDIT:** One other note is that you should provide data with as many places as you want your face to be recognized in. For example, if you just want it to recognize your face in the same lighting/background every time, then you will probably not need very much data, but you should provide most of your data of pictures from that angle so there is a high degree of similarity among what the camera sees and what the data has. Alternatively, if you want to do facial recognition from your phone, for example, there can be many different angles/backgrounds, so you should provide many more examples, all containing a wide variety/combination of these angles/backgrounds for the best results.

Answer (score 0):

How many images should I have in my dataset so as to get good results?

Actually the question is too general which I can give 2 answers. Well, according to the scripts in Python for TensorFlow, you need at least 20 images as the input.

```
if len(file_list) < 20:
  tf.logging.warning(
      'WARNING: Folder has less than 20 images, which may cause issues.')
elif len(file_list) > MAX_NUM_IMAGES_PER_CLASS:
  tf.logging.warning(
      'WARNING: Folder {} has more than {} images. Some images will '
      'never be selected.'.format(dir_name, MAX_NUM_IMAGES_PER_CLASS))
```

It's better to supply input images more than this recommended number as the more data you put in, the high the accuracy of the training and inferencing data. Since you just wanna do a detection based on your face image, then I bet it's so easy that you can just collect it from any photos of your and selfie frequently.

But a GOOD RESULTS not just depends on number of images. Some users might have limited access to the resources. GOOD RESULTS also depends on CNN architecture that you're using. Different architecture or training model will surely give different type of good results. There are a lot of models or architecture out there such as MobileNet and ResNet that are good for CNN Deep Learning.

No matter what type of detection you wish for, in this case `mypic` and `others`, make sure you already classify those images into their respective folders.